# Interface for object whose members are classes

Tags: typescript

I have a module which defines several classes which take type parameters (`<T>`) and implement an interface (`my_interface`).

```
// [my_module.ts]
import {my_interface} from ".\typings.d.ts"
export class Class_A <T> implements my_interface {
    blah blah blah;
}
export class Class_B <T> implements my_interface {
    blah blah blah;
}
```

and I have a `.d.ts` file that defines interfaces for the class instances:

```
// [typings.d.ts]
export interface my_interface <T> {
    blah:blah;
}
```

I want to add an interface that describes the module as a whole, but the following raises a "TS2304: Cannot find name 'T'." error:

```
// [typings.d.ts]
export interface MY_MODULE {
    Class_A: my_interface<T>;
    Class_B: my_interface<T>;
}
```

and the following raises an "TS2314: Generic type 'my_interface' requires 1 type argument(s)" error:

```
// [typings.d.ts]
export interface MY_MODULE {
    Class_A: my_interface;
    Class_B: my_interface;
}
```

Is there a way to create an interface (`MY_MODULE`) to describe the object that is imported when the compiled JS code is imported via:

```
var my_module:MY_MODULE = require("my_module")
```

Comment: There shouldn't be a need to define the type of a module, the compiler should infer everything about the module itself. If you later need to you can do: `typeof my_module`.

Comment: Not when the module is imported from the compiled JS files -- i.e. when the module is installed via `npm` or `bower`.  That's why I'm writing the `.d.ts` file.

Comment: Well, have you tried referencing the definition file: `/// <reference path="path/to/defnitions.d.ts" />` ?

Comment: Yes, that's when the errors messages above occur -- i.e. when the type script compiler encounters the declaration of the `MY_MODULE` interface.

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you're trying to do, but you're not supposed to create an interface to a module.

Comment: Really?  A module is an object like any other.  Why not describe it's shape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to wonder if you're using generics meaningfully here. Anyway, the past of least resistance to do what you'd like to do is this: make `MY_MODULE` generic.

```
export interface MY_MODULE<T> {
    Class_A: my_interface<T>;
    Class_B: my_interface<T>;
}
```

The  parameter will then resolve correctly. In your import you would then type it as

```
var my_module:MY_MODULE<type-here> = require("my_module")
```

if you don't care what gets fed into it, go ahead and do

```
var my_module:MY_MODULE<any> = require("my_module")
```

---

This has some implications. This means that `type_A` and `type_B` are both generic off of the same type. Is this intended? If not, then rather than using `:my_interface<T>` in your type annotation you should fill in the type you're interested in type_A and type_B working on. If you don't care, you can again use `any`.

Would you like to suppress supplying type information until it's used? Perhaps type A and B are collections of some sort and you would like them to carry the type they're initialized on onto later function calls. You can achieve this as well, but you'll need to use a function such as:

```
interface ExampleModule {
    Class_A: <T> (param: T) => my_interface<T>
}
```

or a constructor such as:

```
interface ExampleModule {
    Class_A: { new<T>(): my_interface<T> };
}
```

and then use the generated object.

Comment: The constructor interface is exactly what I was looking for.   Thanks!